Laravel 11 command choice test issue
I am implementing a Laravel 11 command, with choice, and when I test it I receive this message:

Output "blablabla" was not printed.

I tried then the example on the Laravel 11 documentation https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/console-tests
$name = $this->ask('What is your name?');

$language = $this->choice('Which language do you prefer?', [
    'PHP',
    'Ruby',
    'Python',
]);

$this->line('Your name is '.$name.' and you prefer '.$language.'.');


$this->artisan('question')
     ->expectsQuestion('What is your name?', 'Taylor Otwell')
     ->expectsQuestion('Which language do you prefer?', 'PHP')
     ->expectsOutput('Your name is Taylor Otwell and you prefer PHP.')
     ->doesntExpectOutput('Your name is Taylor Otwell and you prefer Ruby.')
     ->expectsOutputToContain('Taylor Otwell')
     ->doesntExpectOutputToContain('you prefer Ruby')
     ->assertExitCode(0);

but I receive this message:

Output does not contain "Taylor Otwell".

How do I test a choice command using Laravel 11?

Looks like a bug to me. You can  I would raise it in GitHub with them. It seems that having expectsOutput prevents all expectsOutputToContain from working

Just in case, this is where you should report it: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues
